# How do I Deploy F# Azure WebJob?

Tags: azure, f#, azure-webjobs

Can I actually deploy F# console app as Azure WebJob? Can't find a proper option in VS2017 :(

And if it's possible, can you have a look at my code? Would it work as it is if I will deploy it as AzureWebJob? Do I need to change something?

```
open FSharp.Data;
open System
open System.Net.Mail


let server = "smtp.gmail.com" 
let sender = "fsharpie.send@gmail.com" 
let password = "password" 
let port = 587
let SendTest email topic msg = 
    use msg = 
        new MailMessage(
            sender, email, topic, 
            msg)
    let client = new SmtpClient(server, port)
    client.EnableSsl <- true
    client.Timeout <- 20000
    client.DeliveryMethod <- SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
    client.UseDefaultCredentials <- false
    client.Credentials <- System.Net.NetworkCredential(sender, password)
    client.Send msg


let metaTitle (doc:HtmlDocument) =
    doc.Descendants "meta"
    |> Seq.choose (fun x ->
        match x.AttributeValue("name"), x.AttributeValue("property") with
        | "title", _
        | "headline", _
        | "twitter:title", _
        | _, "og:title" ->
            Some(x.AttributeValue("content"))
        | _, _ -> None
    )

let titles (doc:HtmlDocument) =
    let tagged (tag:string) =
        doc.Descendants tag |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.InnerText())
    Seq.concat [tagged "title"; metaTitle doc; tagged "h1"]

let title (doc:HtmlDocument) =
    titles doc |> Seq.tryHead


let finalTitle (link:string) = try
                                link
                                |> HtmlDocument.Load
                                |> titles
                                |> Seq.head
                                with 
                                | :? Exception as ex -> ex.Message

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let website = "website.com"
    if(finalTitle website <> "expected title")
    then
            SendTest "result@gmail.com" "Status: Failed" (website + " is down :( ")

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I actually deploy F# console app as Azure WebJob?

Yes, we can delploy F# console app as Azure WebJob

> Can't find a proper option in VS2017

Publish F# project as Azure webjob from VS2017 tool directly is not supported  currently.

But we can publish the F# project from Azure Portal.I did a demo for it. The following is my detail steps:

1.Create  F# project with VS2017

[image]

2.Install the WebJob SKD in the project

[image]

3.Build the project and Zip the release or debug file in the bin folder

[image]

4.Upload the Zip file from Azure portal

[image]

5.Config the Appsetting with Storage connection string

[image]

6.Check the webjob with Azure Kudu(https://yourwebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net) tool

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an .exe from your f# code, create a zip from the output folder and upload it to Azure.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dave_crooks_dev_blog/2015/02/18/deploying-f-web-job-to-azure/

Another option is use Azure Functions which is the evolution of Azure WebJobs and has support for f#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-fsharp